# Apache httpd redirects from localhost not working in Docker

Tags: apache, docker, redirect

To publish some ontology files I want to add redirects to [w3id.org](https://w3id.org/), which is simply an Apache HTTP Server, that can be configured through `.htaccess` files in [a public GitHub repository](https://github.com/perma-id/w3id.org).

Since I am not familiar with the Apache server and HTTP redirects at all, I tried to get `w3id` running in a local Docker container. Therefore, I followed the instruction on the [`httpd` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) and created a `Dockerfile` containing:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

Of course, I replaced `./public-html/` with the path to my local `w3id` repository files.

I used the commands below to build and run the container:

```
$ docker build -t w3id.org .
$ docker run -dit --name w3id.org -p 8080:80 w3id.org
```

Afterwards, I can successfully access an endpoint at `localhost:8080` which provides the simple HTML landing page of the `w3id` project.

However, if I try to access for example `localhost:8080/security`, I will not get redirected in any way, in contrast to when I access [`w3id.org/security`](https://w3id.org/security), which points me to [`web-payments.org/vocabs/security`](https://web-payments.org/vocabs/security) like intended. Instead, the request provides an overview about all files inside the specific directory `security`, which seems to be the default behaviour for all requests.

The example `.htaccess` file inside the `security` directory contains:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified$
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ https://web-payments.org/vocabs/security [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^v1$ https://web-payments.org/contexts/security-v1.jsonld [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^v2$ https://web-payments.org/contexts/security-v2.jsonld [R=302,L]
```

Is this caused by my `Dockerfile` or the way I run the container?
Do I need to enable redirects in Apache?
Or maybe caused by missing HTTPS in my local setup?

How can I locally setup and test external redirects in `.htaccess` files?

Comment: Some information is missing from the question - how are the redirects set up? Is it a redirect in .htaccess? Can you paste the relevant section from your htaccess? In any case, I do not believe it is related to docker, or the way you run it or HTTPs (unless the htaccess specifically does https related redirect).

Comment: I did not create a `.htaccess` file yet, because I wanted to follow the files of other projects in the repository. However, none of them are working inside my local test setup (Docker container). Nevertheless I added the content of the `.htaccess` file inside the example directory `security` to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to enable `mod_rewrite` and enable overriding with `.htaccess`.

See the below Dockerfile for a working reference:

```
FROM httpd:alpine

RUN sed -i '/LoadModule rewrite_module/s/^#//g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf && \
    sed -i 's#AllowOverride [Nn]one#AllowOverride All#' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

WORKDIR /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/

COPY ./public .
```

Then, redirecting with `.htaccess` can be done like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /whatever http://example.com
```

I would suggest trying this (as is) first in the docroot, to ensure your redirects work, and then see if you want / need to move your `.htaccess` deeper to the security directory, and tweak further as needed.

Finally, since I am not sure if you pasted the exact docker commands you are using or just partial commands, I would suggest mounting the public directory to the container during development, this way you do not need to rebuild on every change for debug.

```
$ docker build -t temp .
$ docker run -i -p 3000:80 -v $PWD/public:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ temp
```